# App disappeared from TestFlight due to ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - _CMTimebaseCreateWithMasterClock

Tags: build, testflight, xcode14.3

I have encountered an issue with my app when submitting it to TestFlight. After submission, the app disappeared from TestFlight, and I received the following error message:

ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - _CMTimebaseCreateWithMasterClock

We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "App Name" 1.0 (19). Please correct the following issues, then upload again.

ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app references non-public symbols in Frameworks/libksygpulive.framework/libksygpulive: _CMTimebaseCreateWithMasterClock. If method names in your source code match the private Apple APIs listed above, altering your method names will help prevent this app from being flagged in future submissions. In addition, note that one or more of the above APIs may be located in a static library that was included with your app. If so, they must be removed. For further information, visit the Technical Support Information at http://developer.apple.com/support/technical/

I Try some suggested approcahes to check permissions in Plist but unsuccessful.

Comment: Not only you, there are multiple people facing this issue from last 24 hours. Please check this thread : https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/733318

Comment: I think you can reply to apple (in the resolution centre) and ask apple to review it again, I think it is apple bug and your application was reviewed by apple's AI engine, just message them and I think it will be resolved or at least they will tell you exact problem

Comment: @MZubairShamshad Thank you for your response. I have posted a comment in the thread, and I'm following it closely. I hope that the Apple team will provide a response as soon as possible. I appreciate your assistance and guidance in resolving this issue.

Comment: @SultanAli Thank you for your response. Let's try your suggestion.

Comment: Great news! The issue has been successfully resolved. It turns out that it was an issue on Apple's side. After uploading the new build, the application is now working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

According to the above comments, this problem was from Apple side, so, we can conclude that we always try to send build multiple times
Happy coding ☺️